# React Native Android TV Box - Save Files on disk

Tags: react-native, android-tv, file-access, local-database, tvbox

I need to develop an application for Android Tv Box in React Native which works offline. At a certain point (when the device has internet) a data/file download is performed.
The data should be stored in a local database, while the files in the TV Box's memory.
Then the app shows the info, recovering the information from the local database and memory (images/videos).

Is this possible?
Can files be stored in the TV Box's memory?
And what about using a local database for the rest of the data?

Supposedly the device that the client is going to use is VONTAR X88 PRO.

Thanks!